# Jquery dialogs order

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have two Jquery dialogs. The second one opens on top of the first one. How to keep the second one always on top ---> now when I click on the bottom one the top one hides under the first but stays opened.

I tried using highest `z-index` but it did't help.
I don't want to use `modal` option on the dialog.

You can play around here: http://jsfiddle.net/2jYEP/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [focus event](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-focus) of jquery ui dialog to keep the zIndex of first dialog to lowest. Here is the working fiddle:

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2jYEP/3/)

```
....
$("#div1").dialog({
         autoOpen: false,
         autoResize: true,
         resizable:false,
         dragable:false,
         focus: function(e, ui){
          $(this).parent(".ui-dialog").css("z-index", 0);
        }
     });
....
```

Whenever dialog gets focus the jquery ui code set its zIndex at top. So we just alter that behavior and set the first dialog zIndex to lowest on focus.